# Не изменяется текст Label tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, gui

Возникла проблема с изменением текста Label'а с помощью text = переменная, которая является StringVar().get(). В прикрепленном участке кода обратите внимание на bilok_label, jir_label,  vyg_label и calories_label(). С помощью функции choose_dish создаеться дочернее окно, в котором пользователь указывает нужные данные для функции add_a_dish, в которой уже собственно переменные calories_svar, bilok_svar, vyg_svar и jir_svar получают новые значения.

```
def choose_dish(name, massa):
    window.destroy()
    print_name(name=name)
    base_of_dishes = open('dishes.txt', encoding= 'UTF-8')
    for line in base_of_dishes:
        line = line.split(',')
        if line[0] == name:
            calories_svar.set(str(int(float(data_of_user_gl[8]) + round(float(line[4])*float(massa)))))
            
            bilok_svar.set(str(int(float(data_of_user_gl[10]) + round(float(line[1])*float(massa)))))

            jir_svar.set(str(int(float(data_of_user_gl[12]) + round(float(line[2])*float(massa)))))

            vyg_svar.set(str(int(float(data_of_user_gl[14]) + round(float(line[3])*float(massa)))))
            
            base_of_dishes.close()
            break


def add_a_dish():
    
    

    a = []
    base_of_dishes = open('dishes.txt', encoding= 'UTF-8')
    for line in base_of_dishes:
        line = line.split(',')
        a.append(str(line[0]))
    base_of_dishes.close()
    
    grams = tk.IntVar()
    global window
    window = tk.Toplevel(master=calculator_window)
    window.geometry('300x200')
    window.title('Додати страву')
    
    tk.Label(window ,text='Оберіть страву з списку введіть її приблизну вагу:', font = 'Arial 8').pack()
    
    dishes_box = tk.ttk.Combobox(window, values=a)
    dishes_box.pack()
  
    tk.Label(window, text='Вага в грамах:').pack()
    entry1 = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=grams)
    entry1.pack()
    
    b1 = tk.Button(window, text='ОК', command=lambda: choose_dish(dishes_box.get(), massa=grams.get()))
    b1.pack(pady=10)
    tk.Button(window, text='Створити нову страву').pack(pady=10)

def calculator(data_of_user):
    global current_password
    global current_login
    current_login = data_of_user_gl[0]
    current_password = data_of_user_gl[1]
    global bilok_svar
    global calories_svar
    global jir_svar
    global vyg_svar
    bilok_svar = tk.StringVar()
    bilok_svar.set(str(data_of_user_gl[10]))
    calories_svar = tk.StringVar()
    calories_svar.set(str(data_of_user_gl[8]))
    jir_svar = tk.StringVar()
    jir_svar.set(str(data_of_user_gl[12]))
    vyg_svar = tk.StringVar()
    vyg_svar.set(str(data_of_user_gl[14]))










    root.destroy()
    calories_now = data_of_user_gl[8]
    calories = str(calories_now) + '/' + str(data_of_user_gl[7])
    bilok_now = data_of_user_gl[10]
    bilok = str(bilok_now) + '/' + str(data_of_user_gl[9])
    jir_now = data_of_user_gl[12]
    jir = str(jir_now) + '/' + str(data_of_user_gl[11])
    vyg_now = data_of_user_gl[14]
    vyg = str(vyg_now) + '/' + str(data_of_user_gl[13])
    
    global calculator_window
    calculator_window = tk.Tk()
    calculator_window.title('Калькулятор калорій')
    calculator_window.geometry('250x270')
    calculator_window.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
    
    calories_var = tk.StringVar()
    calories_var.set(calories)
    bilok_var = tk.StringVar()
    bilok_var.set(bilok)
    jir_var = tk.StringVar()
    jir_var.set(jir)
    vyg_var = tk.StringVar()
    vyg_var.set(vyg)
    tk.Label(calculator_window,text = 'Ваші калорії за день:', font ='Arial 11').pack()
    calories_label = tk.Label(calculator_window, text=calories_svar.get(), font = 'Arial 18')
    calories_label.pack()
    


    label_0 = tk.Label(calculator_window,text='Білки:', font='Arial 10')
    bilok_label = tk.Label(calculator_window,text = bilok_svar.get(), font = 'Arial 12')
    label_1 = tk.Label(calculator_window,text='Жири:', font='Arial 10')
    jir_label = tk.Label(calculator_window,text = jir_svar.get(), font = 'Arial 12')
    label_2 = tk.Label(calculator_window,text='Вуглеводи:', font='Arial 10')
    vyg_label = tk.Label(calculator_window,text = vyg_svar.get(), font = 'Arial 12')


    label_0.pack()
    bilok_label.pack()
    label_1.pack()
    jir_label.pack()
    label_2.pack()
    vyg_label.pack()

    tk.Button(calculator_window,text = 'Додати страву', command=add_a_dish).pack()






    calculator_window.mainloop()
```

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
calculator_window.update()
```

Или

```
calculator_window.update_idletasks()
```